# Capturing image from camera and setting it to image view

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app which captures an image from camera and sets it to imageview.

Here is the code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 2);
        }
    });

@Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
             Toast.makeText(this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             try {
                 Bitmap bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData())
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
```

The imageview is empty.

but when I use this:

```
Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Instead of:

```
Bitmap bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData())
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I am getting the image.

What is the difference in those 2 methods why am I getting the correct output in the 2nd one

Comment: where is `;` after `data.getData())`

Comment: That is just copy-paste error, I didn't make error in the IDE

Comment: data.getData()==null ? You got a bitmap. There is no uri. The camera app did save nothing to disk. It only gave you a bitmap.

Comment: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` has never been documented to return a `Uri`, so `data.getData()` should return `null`.

Comment: "Why does data.getExtra() return a bundle?" -- the role of extras is covered in [the `Intent` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent). "How bundle can get a bitmap?" -- [`Bitmap` implements `Parceable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap), and you can put (small) `Parcelable` objects as values in a `Bundle`.